# Magento get products from a specific category with name, image and description

Tags: php, magento

Asked this before but unfortunately there were no answers to this question.

How I can get the products from a specific category with name, image and description?

Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($your_category_id);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products = $collection->getItems();
```

Not entirely sure about the image attribute, if it fails you can always for an individual product execute a `$product->load($product->getId())` to load all data.

Comment: Hi Lucasmus. Thanks for your comment. But how i can print the attributes?

Comment: Hmm, for example: `foreach ($products as $product) { echo "name: {$product->getName()}, description: {$product->getDescription()}, image: {$product->getImage()}";}`.